# Instagram API not returning user media

Tags: api, instagram

I am trying to use the instagram API to get a users photos. I am using this plugin

https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API

I have followed an example, the profile I am connecting with definietely has posts on it but it returns but the data is empty

Here's my code

```
    $instagram = new \MetzWeb\Instagram\Instagram(array(
        'apiKey'      => 'client_id',
        'apiSecret'   => 'client_secret',
        'apiCallback' => URL::to('instagram-redirect')
    ));

    if(isset($_GET{'code'}))
    {
        // grab OAuth callback code
        $code = $_GET['code'];

        $data = $instagram->getOAuthToken($code);

        $instagram->setAccessToken($data);

        $media = $instagram->getUserMedia();

        Helper::pr([$data,$media]);
    }
    else
    {
        echo $instagram->getLoginUrl();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because on 17th Nov 2015 Instagram switched to new version of API. Cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API does not support this new version. More on it here https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API/issues/182